# Exibição de Custom Post Type atrelada à Posts comuns

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-types

Criei um `custom post type` e nele 4 posts, e chamei certinho no código, creio eu, só que eles só aparecem quando deixo algum post criado no `post` `type` `Posts` que é o padrão do WordPress.

```
<div class="all-recipe" >
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'posts_blog',
                    'status' => 'publish',
                    'numberposts' => 4,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                $query = get_posts( $args );
            ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : foreach( $query as $post ) : setup_postdata ( $post ); ?>  
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0;">
                    <div class="recipe-posts-principais" style="background: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)">
                        <button>Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>
                        <div class="block-infos" style="display: none">
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <h3><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h3>
                            <span><?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
                            <h1> <?php echo $meta['mensagem'][0]; ?> </h1>
                            <p> <?php echo $meta['descricao-humanidade'][0]; ?> </p>
                            <a href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?>">Saiba mais</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente a função have_posts() verifica se existem registros do tipo Post.

Comment: Como faço pra poder puxar só do custom post type que criei?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

`<?php if (have_posts()) : foreach( $query as $post ) : setup_postdata ( $post ); ?>`

O que mostra que o seu relato está correto: *só aparecem quando deixo algum post criado no post type Posts*. Se não especificado, `have_posts()` vai fazer uma busca no objeto de *query* global, e não no que você tentou especificar logo acima. Eu digo *tentou*, uma vez que você não o fez explicitamente. Apesar de `get_posts()` fazer o uso da `WP_Query` internamente ([veja documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)), todos os outros métodos que essa classe proporciona não estarão disponíveis, e é exatamente isso que você deveria fazer.

Para tal, experimente montar sua query da seguinte forma:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'posts_blog',
    'status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Dessa forma, `$query` se torna um objeto da consulta, e não apenas um objeto de posts. Para o *loop*, você pode montar

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        # code ...
    }
    // Restaura o objeto de consulta
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Escrevendo o seu código dessa maneira, você retira a dependência da existência de um *post* comum.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Caio.
Chegando em casa irei testar.

Comment: como to engatinhando ainda tanto no WP como no PHP, só não consegui ainda inserir de forma correta meu código (divs) junto a esse loop ae.

Comment: Deu certo Caio, agora mesmo excluindo o post no post type Posts, os posts do meu CPT não somem mais não.


Só tenho que conseguir exibir certinho agora só os posts referentes as taxonomias que colocar nos argumentos, mesmo colocando, ta aparecendo todos que tem no Custom Post Type, e não só os que marquei a categoria...

Comment: @PeterRoberto Se a resposta lhe ajudou, não esqueça de marcá-la como correta. Quanto à sua dúvida sobre taxonomias, você acaba configurando uma pergunta completamente diferente. Experimente procurar nas perguntas aqui, pq eu acho que eu mesmo já respondi algo do tipo. Se não encontrar, abra uma nova pergunta e a comunidade com certeza vai te ajudar.

Comment: Opa, valeu demais Caio, a resposta ajudou muito sim e sobre a taxonomia já consegui resolver tb, thanks bro!